# Proper way of converting C's uint32 to int in java

Tags: java, c, binary, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

I am building a project which consists of multiple components and these components communicate with each other in byte arrays using sockets. The problem is one component is written in C and supports Unsigned primitive types while other components are written in Java and does not support Unsigned types. I am trying to develop support for Unsigned types in Java. I am new to Java. Can anyone please tell me the proper way to decode uint32 and uint64 from a byte array.

I am using the following functions for conversion of int32 and int64

```
public static int int32Converter(byte b[], int start) {
    return ((b[start] << 24) & 0xff000000 |(b[start + 1] << 16) & 0xff0000
            | (b[start + 2] << 8) & 0xff00 | (b[start + 3]) & 0xff);
}
public static long int64Converter(byte buf[], int start) {
    return ((buf[start] & 0xFFL) << 56) | ((buf[start + 1] & 0xFFL) << 48)
            | ((buf[start + 2] & 0xFFL) << 40)
            | ((buf[start + 3] & 0xFFL) << 32)
            | ((buf[start + 4] & 0xFFL) << 24)
            | ((buf[start + 5] & 0xFFL) << 16)
            | ((buf[start + 6] & 0xFFL) << 8)
            | ((buf[start + 7] & 0xFFL) << 0);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exactly "convert" them. The closest you'll find to handling unsigned values is Guava's [`UnsignedInteger`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger.html) and its utility class `UnsignedInts`. There is the same for bytes, shorts and longs too.

Note about your code, don't be bothere writing such stuff by hand, use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
public static int bytesToInt(final byte[] array, final int start)
{
     final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(array); // big endian by default
     buf.position(start);
     buf.put(array);
     return buf.position(start).getInt();
}
```

Using Guava for an unsigned int:

```
public static UnsignedInteger bytesToUnsignedInt(final byte[] array, final int start)
{
         return UnsignedInteger.fromIntBits(bytesToInt(array, start);
}
```

However, I suspect that `UnsignedInts` is really what you want. (for comparison, printing them out etc)

Answer (score 1):

This code will copy the bytes from the array into an int. The byte at index 0 (value 1) is the LSB. Index 3 (value 15) is the MSB:

```
byte[] bytes = { 1, 3, 7, 15 };
int result = 0; 
for (int i = 0 ; i < bytes.length ; i++) { 
    result |= bytes[i]<<(i*8); 
}
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

Prints:

1111000001110000001100000001

If you change it to long and give it a longer byte array, and you change the Integer.toBinaryString() to one from Long it will work for long, too.

From now on you should never print your long/int to the screen as regular decimal values. Print the binary or the hex value of it when you need to compare with your eyes; Long.toHexString(long).

Answer (score -1):

If the values of the `uint32` never goes over 2^31 then you can store them in a Java int. If not then you will need a java Long.

For uint64 then if the value never goes over 2^63 then you will be able to use long, otherwise you will need BigInteger.

In either case if the algorithm you are porting relies on wrapping (i.e. values overflowing integer and going back to 0) then you will need to add your own manual logic to handle those scenarios.